# Select motion path from curve in Maya Python

Tags: python, maya

I need to obtain the motion path attached to a curve in maya using Python.
This is the situation as shown in the editor:

[image: Description of situation]

I want to obtain **motionPath1** by calling a method on **curve3** since they look like they are related.

However, I have tried pleny of list methods (listAttr, listHierarchy, etc) but they only return the **curveShape3**.

What is the command, if it exists at all, to get the name of the motion path in Python knowing the object **curve3**?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You need to get motion path node name from curve shape.

```
import maya.cmds as cmd
shape = cmd.listRelatives( 'curve3' )
mPath = cmd.listConnections( shape, type = 'motionPath')
print mPath
```